# an error accurred while mounting /

Tags: 12.04

When I enter the command:

```
mount -o remount command, rw /
```

The response is:

```
[ 1369.701286] EXT4-fs (sda1) : Unrecognized mount option "remount-ro" or missing value
mount : / not mounted or bad option
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (released 2012.April hence 12.04, with a five year service life) is EOL (end-of-life) and unsupported on this site.   (If you're using 12.04 ESM its not eol but is unsupported here too.  As for your command, please use backticks (\`) to make your actual command easier to read, but I'd suggest moving to a supported release of Ubuntu anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/fstab` is broken. It probably intially said `errors=remount-ro` which is correct ([details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707118/what-do-the-fstab-mount-options-errors-remount-ro-mean)), then somebody turned it manually into `remount-ro` which is an invalid option.

For a root filesystem this makes OS unusable. You need to boot from DVD and repair.